# Show dialog only once after check checkbox

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I have in my oncreate a dialog with a checkbox. This checkbox if checked makes dialog not shows the next time i open the application.. I've saved the checkbox state in the sharedpreferences and it goes, it shows me if i've checked or not the checkbox but the dialog still open on startup..What's wrong?

EDIT

// Dialog
    View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("checkBox"));

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(buttonView.getId()){
        case R.id.checkbox:
        saveInSp("checkBox",isChecked);

        break;
        }
    }
}); 
checkBox.setText("Never show it");

SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean hasBeenChecked = preferences.getBoolean("checkbox", false);

if (!hasBeenChecked) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(" TITLE");
    builder.setMessage(" blablabla ")
           .setView(checkBoxView)
           .setCancelable(false)

           .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           }).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- (non-essential) Remove the `saveInSp` from the anonymous `OnCheckedChangeListener` and add it to the activity, for instance
- (non-essential) You can call `saveInSp` from the listener by referencing `MyActivity.this.saveInSp`
- Then, before initializing and showing your alert...

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  boolean hasBeenChecked = preferences.getBoolean("checkBox", false);

  if (!hasBeenChecked) {

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle(" TITLEs");
      builder.setMessage(" blablabla ")
             .setView(checkBoxView)
             .setCancelable(false)

             .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                 }
             }).show();
  }
  ```

Comment: But what have i to remove? the `saveInSp`? The first part isn't clear for me sorry

Comment: I mean, i understand what you've done but i don't know what i have to do with the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: @David_D the first part is not essential to the solution, but rather a better way to implement it. You're using an anonymous class (your listener) for the checkbox "on check changed" event. However, you are adding a the method to save into the shared preferences as a method of your anonymous class, rather than reuse it in your whole activity (or better, have a singleton class take care of that throughout the whole application). Again, not at all essential to solving your issue, sorry for the confusion. The 3rd point and the code below it are what matters.

Comment: So i can remove the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`? and use only youre code? Becase i've tryied but the dialog stay there :(

Comment: @David_D Nononononononono. Just add the code I posted after `checkBox.setText("Never show it");`.

Comment: @David_D yes. Although I wouldn't have edited your question for that :) But yes.

Comment: The dialog still appears every time i open the application :(

Comment: Have you another idea?

Comment: @David_D Small bug: `boolean hasBeenChecked = preferences.getBoolean("checkBox", false);` Note the capital "B".

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your saved value is shared preferences before calling AlertDialog.show().

Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(" TITLEs");
            builder.setMessage(" blablabla ")
                   .setView(checkBoxView)
                   .setCancelable(false)

                   .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   }).show();

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

if (getFromSP("checkBox")) {
   dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Argh. Crash..The first time i can open the application. When i click the checkbox and i re-open the app i get a crash. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`